# SUMIF then restart count

Tags: sql, ssms-2017

How can I do a SUMIF function so that it adds up values when the value in another column is "False", but then when it hits a value that is "True", it restarts the count over again, but includes the value of the first "True" encounter in the SUM calculation? I would also like it so that it adds up the value in chronological order.

I did some research and I think I need to use an over partition and make a row number column to call all row number = "1", but I'm not sure how to do this.

Edit: the Sum should also include the "distance" value for the first "true" value it encounters

Edit 2: Ultimately, I am trying to calculate the average distance each vehicle travels before an Alert is triggered to "True" which means it needs to be taken to the shop to be fixed. Perhaps there is a better way to do this than what I was originally thinking?

Sorry for the poor phrasing...

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.  Presumably, you also want this per vehicle, even though your question does not explicitly say this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to define groups.  It sounds like you want the definition to be the number of "trues" up to and including a given row.  Then, you can do a cumulative sum within each group.  So:

```
select t.*,
       sum(distance) over (partition by vehicleid, grp
                           order by date
                           rows between unbounded preceding and current row  
                          )    
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when alert = 'True' then 1 else 0 end) over
                 (partition by vehicleid
                  order by date
                  rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                 ) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b5ce1a4d8aa1f381be1772d595ebe68f) is a db<>fiddle that illustrates that this code works.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this query it seems to be summing up the values, but it is not resetting when it hits a "True" value. It just keeps adding up. Edit: What I'm ultimately trying to do is calculate average distance a vehicle is traveling before an alert is triggered to "true". Maybe there is a better method than what I was originally thinking?

Comment: @Empyz . . . There was a type.  `grp` wasn't being used in the outer query.

Comment: Hi Gordan. Thank you for the help! I'm not sure I follow... I tried running the query after adding and removing grp, but the counts don't seem to reset at a "True" value, and the dates don't seem to be in order either. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: From my understanding of the query above, the "grp" column should only contain the values "1" or "0", but when I run this on my machine, I get values ranging from 0-40. Is this supposed to occur?

Comment: @Empyz . . . There is no reason that `grp` would be limited to 0 and 1.  It counts the number of alerts for a vehicle up to a given date.

Comment: ah...okay this is all starting to make sense now... thank you Gordon!

Answer (score 0):

You are right in thinking that you can use SUM analytical function. Something like this will do the cumulative sum for you.
For you to restart the SUM when the alert is True, you include the alert in the partition window and Order by date to achieve the order.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN alert = 'FALSE' 
                THEN distance 
                ELSE 0 
                 END) 
       OVER(PARTITION BY alert 
                ORDER BY date) cumm_sum
     , date
     , alert 
  FROM Table
```